# Laravel Eloquent bulk update, ensure uniqueness

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transactions

I've been breaking my head over this for a good day now. Hope anyone can help me with this.

I have a model `Course` and I want to allow users of the API to bulk update the details of each Course. I've created a nice front-end where users can edit the details Excel like. The front-end sends a PUT request to my API with the new values for each course. The `Course` table looks like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id         | name       | abbrev     | owner_id   | created_at          | updated_at          |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1          | Math B     | MB         | 1          | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 |
| ...        | ...        | ...        | ...        | ...                 | ...                 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Now, there's a few requirements I want to keep in mind:

- The name of the `Course` and the abbreviation should both be UNIQUE (not enforced by MySQL but business requirement).
- The PUT request the user sent doesn't contain all records, only the records that were actually changed by the user.
- Either everything in the PUT request should be updated or nothing should be updated (and an error returned, out of the scope of this question).

**Now the problem is**:
How do I ensure the UNIQUENESS of those two fields without actually making any changes until I know for sure the UNIQUENESS is maintained?

I was thinking of using transactions to first 'stage' all changes, then query the UNIQUENESS of both fields and then either commit or rollback, is that a good approach? Any suggestions for a different one? Can anyone give me any pointers on how to do the transactions in combination with the Eloquent Query Builder?

A second approach I was thinking about is first retrieve all entries from the database, making the changes in the collection returned, somehow check the UNIQUENESS, if UNIQUENESS ensured throw out everything that wasn't changed and save everything that was changed. Problem with this approach is that the database entries are returned as a `Collection` of `Course` objects and the PUT data is an array of `StdObj` objects, thus incompatible for direct operations. Any ideas on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason for not using mysql to enforce uniqueness? So the only change needed in the code is surrounding the code in transaction

Comment: Yes, as I want either everyting to change or nothing, there would be a point in time where not all data is changed yet and to allow in such an intermediate state for data not to be unique so for example two named can be swapped without first NULL-ing the values to be swapped